# How to properly authenticate using Python requests via a POST request

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I am using the REST API for iObeya, I wish to use Python Requests but currently I cannot authenticate with the server. The documentation states that you can authenticate using a POST request and upon return, you should get a cookie called 'JSESSIONID' when the auth is correct.

So far I have this:

```
url = 'https://link-to.com/iobeya/'
auth_url = 'https://link-to.com/iobeya/j_spring_security_check'
headers = {"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"}

session = requests.Session()
session.auth = ("username", "password")

auth = session.post(url, verify=False)

r = session.get(url, verify=False, headers=headers)

print(r.status_code)

print(r.headers)

print(r.cookies)
```

The return of cookies is null. Is this the right way to be doing a auth request using a POST method?

Here is the page describing how the auth API works:
[image]

Comment: No, that's for sending HTTP authentication along with the request. But we can't tell you what the actual answer is because you haven't linked to the API docs.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I would but I don't think its available online. The site is https://www.iobeya.com and I can''t find it. I have an internal PDF.

Comment: Well at least copy the section relating to auth and post it here.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have made an edit to my question to include api information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just wants you to make a normal POST with `username` and `password`.

```
auth_url = 'https://link-to.com/iobeya/j_spring_security_check'

session = requests.Session()
auth = session.post(auth_url, data={'username': username, 'password': password})
```